# Creating more centered circles in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/vO6pNaqolX0?t=256) the designer is able to create concentric circles by clicking within center of the current circle and dragging out a new circle.

The only way I can achieve this is by first turning the circles into paths and then clicking within them.  However the video author is able to skip this somewhow.  Thoughts?

Comment: The technique works for me. He's using the grid to place the circles. Have you switched on snap to grid?

Comment: FWIW, dragging out circles symmetrically is done with Shift-Ctrl dragging. Shift for left/right, up/down symmetry, Ctrl to keep the aspect ratio (i.e. to keep it a circle). You must use the select and transform tool, not the circle  and ellipse tool, to achieve this. To make a new circle from an existing one, use Duplicate or Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video a sparse grid is used for consistent series of diameters and placement. It's defined in document preferences. Other grids must be disabled.

3 snap options must be activated:

- enable snapping
- snap nodes,paths and handles
- snap to grid

Other snaps can cause harm.

Press ESC key to deactivate the selection of the last circle. Otherwise the drawing tool does not draw, but tries to move the selected circle.